# nginx - serve static html if ip is not mine?

Tags: web-server, nginx, ip, ip-address

I'm trying to switch some stuff over to a domain running nginx. Is there a simple way to just put my ip address in the configuration for the subdomain and say "If ip is not mine, then just serve this html file. Otherwise, act like normal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tackle this by using IP based maintenance triggers

Try the following at the bottom of here: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88978,91161

> You could just do it like this in the
>   global section:

```
geo $maintenance { default 0;
80.15x.yy.zz/29 0; # your IPs still allowed
80.15x.yy.zz/29 0; # another bunch of allowed IPs }
```

> and in the server section add this:

```
if ($maintenance) { rewrite ^(.*)$
/yourmaintenancefile.html last; }
```

> When you want to start maintenance
>   just switch the "default 0;" to
>   "default 1;" in the $maintenance block
>   and reload your nginx.
>
> Have a look at
>   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGeoModule